# Unable to start jetty server after upgrade to 9.4.8

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I recently upgraded my jetty server to 9.4.8. After upgrade while i try to execute 'jettyRun' command on my application i get the following error:

```
12:27:58.464 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @3707ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
12:28:01.854 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.8.v20171121, build timestamp: 2017-11-22T02:57:37+05:30, git hash: 82b8fb23f757335bb3329d540ce37a2a2615f0a8
12:28:01.948 [main] INFO  org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyConfigurerImpl - Configuring /id-factory-collab with file:/H:/git/uprgade/fc-parent/fc-web/build/jetty-env.xml
12:28:01.995 [main] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration - Config error at <Get name="sessionManager"><Set name="sessionCookie">FCTID</Set><Set name="sessionIdPathParameterName">none</Set><Set name="sessionIdManager">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager"><Set name="workerName">%%name%%</Set></New>
      </Set></Get>
12:28:02.011 [main] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration - Config error at <Get name="sessionHandler"><Get name="sessionManager"><Set name="sessionCookie">FCTID</Set><Set name="sessionIdPathParameterName">none</Set><Set name="sessionIdManager">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager"><Set name="workerName">%%name%%</Set></New>
      </Set></Get></Get>
12:28:02.011 [main] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.a.g.JettyWebAppContext@486bc9a4{/fc,file:///H:/git/uprgade/fc-parent/fc-web/build/inplaceWebapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.getSessionManager()
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.get(XmlConfiguration.java:740) ~[jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:471) ~[jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.get(XmlConfiguration.java:745) ~[jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:471) ~[jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:351) ~[jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:296) ~[jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$configure.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCajava:125) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyConfigurerImpl.applyContextConfigFile(JettyConfigurerImpl.groovy:54) ~[gretty-runner-jetty94-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyConfigurer$applyContextConfigFile$10.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer.configureWithBaseResource(JettyServerConfigurer.groovy:33) ~[gretty-runner-jetty-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1080) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414) ~[groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430) ~[groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.Closure$call$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtisite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.WebInfConfigurationEx.unpack(WebInfConfigurationEx.groovy:46) ~[gretty-runner-jetty94-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:154) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyWebAppContext.super$10$doStart(JettyWebAppContext.groovy) [gretty-runner-jetty94-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.groovy:44) [gretty-runner-jetty94-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.compostractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:115) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385) [jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle$start$0.call(Unknown Source) [jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:9.4.8.v20171121]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSi:117) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerManager.startServer(JettyServerManager.groovy:45) [gretty-runner-jetty-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:117) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117) [groovy-2.4.11.jar:2.4.11]
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:44) [gretty-runner-2.0.0.jar:na]
```

This is the jetty-env.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="contextPath">/fc</Set>

  <Set name="overrideDescriptor">build/override-web.xml</Set>

  <Get name="sessionHandler">
    <Get name="sessionManager">
      <Set name="sessionCookie">FCTID</Set>
      <Set name="sessionIdPathParameterName">none</Set>
      <Set name="sessionIdManager">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionIdManager">
          <Set name="workerName">%%name%%</Set>
        </New>
      </Set>
    </Get>
  </Get>

</Configure>
```

Could someone please help with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet 3.1 changed Session configuration.

As soon as you hit Jetty 9.x you should have changed to use  [javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html).

Example: Lets take a look at these settings first ...

```xml
<Set name="sessionCookie">FCTID</Set>
<Set name="sessionIdPathParameterName">none</Set>
```

These set a cookie name and attempts to not use/disable the URL tracking mode (this technique does nothing in Servlet 3.1 btw)

**in `embedded-jetty`:**

```java
SessionHandler sessionHandler = webAppContext.getSessionHandler();
sessionHandler.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("FCTID");
sessionHandler.setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
```

**or used in a `ServletContextListener`:**

```java
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode;

public class SesssionContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        context.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("FCTID");
        context.setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
    }
}
```

**or using `WEB-INF/web.xml`:**

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <name>FCTID</name>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**About `HashSessionIdManager`:**

The old `HashSessionIdManager` was a "In Memory" session id manager designed for testing purposes, it wasn't meant to be used in a production sense.

There is only 1 Session Id Manager anymore, called `DefaultSessionIdManager`.

It is also a Server component, not a WebApp specific component.

**About `workerName`:**

You'll need to either set that `workerName` on the server level, or use the `JETTY_WORKER_INSTANCE` system environment variable to set the workerName suffix for that server on startup.

`workerName` starts with `"node"` and will take the `JETTY_WORKER_INSTANCE` value and append it, resulting in `workerName = "node" + JETTY_WORKER_INSTANCE;`.

Some things to take into account when assigning `workerName`.

1. It is a Server level configuration.
2. It is the same `workerName` for all WebApp's on the server.
3. It should only have letters or digits in its name. (no whitespace, no punctuation, no other characters are allowed)
4. Depending on the WebApp's chosen Session Data Store or Data Cache, it can be prefixed with a cluster name from those configurations.

**Some other observations:**

Your `jetty-env.xml` is attempting to do things that the `jetty-env.xml` cannot handle.

```xml
<Set name="contextPath">/fc</Set>
```

It is far too late in the WebApp lifecycle to change the context path in the `jetty-env.xml`.

```xml
<Set name="overrideDescriptor">build/override-web.xml</Set>
```

The `overrideDescriptor` has already been assigned, read, and used before the `jetty-env.xml` has been looked at.  This action causes no change as its far too late in the WebApp lifecycle to change this value in the `jetty-env.xml`.

Both of those settings should be moved to the `${jetty.base}/webapps/<context>.xml` file.

Once you are done moving those 2 settings, and update to use the `javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig`, you'll no longer have a `jetty-env.xml`.